# How does the device deletion actually work?

Tags: android-management-api

With the Android Management API, I delete a device using the [enterpises.devices.delete](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/delete) method. This works fine if the device has a data connection.

However, what happens if the device is offline? If the device is turned off, then turned on several weeks after, will the device be deleted once online again?

I need to understand this logic, so that I can decide when to remove the device from my database.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually tested how things work when a device is offline and usually the case is that Android Device Policy has great queuing mechanism, once and when the device gets access to internet it syncs the latest policy changes if any or in your case it would delete the device.

So you can delete the device from your DB when you actually send the `delete` request.

Comment: Your welcome @Florian, I'd suggest you to test it out to confirm the same :)